# Phonetic characters of Arabic emphatic consonants

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, arabic, articulation

My native language is Korean. I'm not learning Arabic, but I'm curious anyway.

Refer to the following link for the letter names I recorded myself: [Arabic pharyngeal consonants](https://soundcloud.com/dannyu-ndos/sets/arabic-pharyngeal-consonants)

I think I can pronounce plain /ħ/ and /ʕ/ properly.

For the pharyngealized fricatives /sˤ/ and /zˤ/, I understand them as coarticulated [s͜ħ] and [z͜ʕ]. Is this a correct analysis?

For /dˤ/, I tend to realize it as implosive [ɗ]. Is this an acceptable allophone?

For /tˤ/, I'm not even sure what I'm realizing it as. Is it a pharyngeal-released affricate?

<s>Did I pronounce them properly?</s>

As the comments say, I pronounce them properly. So I have a remaining question. Did I phonetically analyze them correctly? (Essentially, the questions above.)

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: @amegnunsen That's a relief. Yet I demand some phonological analysis.

Comment: Phonetic is not the same as phonology. So, I cannot propose you a phonological analysis.

Comment: @amegnunsen Phonetical analysis is also appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: close enough. You round [ħ,ʕ].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Co-articulation" and/or "double articulation" is something the IPA has a hard time representing. And to a first approximation, `[s͜ħ]` isn't *wrong*. ص does indeed involve two constrictions, one up in the front of the mouth where `[s]` happens, and one back in the pharynx where `[ħ]` happens.

The reason it's not usually transcribed this way is that **not all constrictions are created equal**. Think of other doubly-articulated consonants like `[kʷ]`. The constriction at the velum is complete, blocking off the airflow entirely, but the constriction at the lips is weaker and only serves to "color" the sound. A "true" co-articulated consonant requires two roughly-equivalent constrictions, like `[k͡p]`.

Similarly, the back constriction in ص isn't as complete as in `[ħ]`: it's more like an approximant than a fricative. So the typical IPA rendition treats it as a "coloring", like the labial articulation in `[kʷ]`, and marks it with a superscript instead of a full letter: `[sˤ]`. The superscript `ˤ` is shorthand for "pharyngeal-colored" or "with a weak/secondary pharyngeal articulation", just like `ʷʲˠˀ` for "labial", "palatal", "velar", and "glottal" respectively.

Comment: Strange thing is, I've seen IPA that represents coarticulated stops (including nasals), but never coarticulated fricatives or approximants. Is that because they assimilate to "colored" versions of the other?

Comment: @DannyuNDos I imagine it's really hard to get simultaneous friction at two different points. For approximants, they happen: w is labiovelar, ɥ is labiopalatal. The common ones just get symbols of their own.

Answer (score 1):

> For the pharyngealized fricatives /sˤ/ and /zˤ/, I understand them as
>   coarticulated [s͜ħ] and [z͜ʕ]. Is this a correct analysis?

No.

> For /dˤ/, I tend to realize it as implosive [ɗ]. Is this an acceptable
>   allophone?

No.

> For /tˤ/, I'm not even sure what I'm realizing it as. Is it a
>   pharyngeal-released affricate?

No.

The pharyngealized consonants in Arabic are produced by spreading and flattening the back of the tongue. There is no co-articulation involved.

This book is old but still very good: https://archive.org/details/ThePhoneticsOfArabic-W.H.T.Gairdner/page/n2

Comment: There is a double articulation, two places of articulation (back and front).

Comment: @amegnunsen. That is correct. But to analyse ص as "coarticulated [s͜ħ] " is dead wrong.

Comment: If [ɗ] isn't an acceptable allophone, does that mean my ض doesn't sound correctly?

Comment: Your ض is not bad. Your ط sounds like [tw], That is wrong.

Comment: My advice is to start with the pharyngealised l in الله. That will give you the right tongue position. @DannyuNDos